# can't connect to the NVR of Unv and Hikvision with the following code. (it works for all IP camera)

Tags: c#, .net, rtsp, onvif

I cannot get profiles of NVR but it works for IP cameras. my target is to archive NVR and IP camera connection get RTSP of the respected channel right now I am trying to get RTSP for 1st profile hardcode. I am reactjs intern so I do not know much of c#. i can succefully connect to ip cameras get there Profiles snapshot and also can get rtsp url using devicemgmt nugect and onvif/media.wsdl service web reference

```
        public static string GetOnvifUrl(string ipAddress){ 
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress)) 
           UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://" + ipAddress + "/onvif/device_service");
            string[] array = ipAddress.Split(':');
            uriBuilder.Host = array[0];
            if (array.Length == 2)
            {
                uriBuilder.Port = Convert.ToInt16(array[1]);
            }
    
            return uriBuilder.ToString();
        }
    
        public CustomBinding GetBinding()
        {
            HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransportBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
            httpTransportBindingElement.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
            return new CustomBinding(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8), httpTransportBindingElement);
        }
    
        [Obsolete]
        public async void getStreamURL(string cameraAddress, string userName, string password)
        {
            try
            { var messageElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()
                {
                    MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None)
                };
                HttpTransportBindingElement httpBinding = new()
                {
                    AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest
                };
                string OnvifUrl = GetOnvifUrl(cameraAddress);
    
                devicemgmt.DeviceClient deviceClient = new devicemgmt.DeviceClient(GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(OnvifUrl));
                deviceClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = userName;
                deviceClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = password;
              
              // Using MEDIAClient because devicemgmt does not support getstreamuri 
                CustomBinding bind = new(messageElement, httpBinding);
                MediaClient mediaClient = new (bind, new EndpointAddress(OnvifUrl));
    
                // DeviceAgent deviceClient = new (ipAddressTextBox.Text,UsernameTextBox.Text,PasswordTextBox.Text);
                mediaClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = userName;
                mediaClient.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = password;
    
    
           (this gives Errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr for NVR attached belowe)
                GetProfilesResponse response = await mediaClient.GetProfilesAsync();
    
               
                var ProfileToken = response.Profiles[0].token;
    
                if (ProfileToken != null)
                {
                 
                    var snapshotUriResponse = mediaClient.GetSnapshotUriAsync(ProfileToken);
                    string snapshotUri = snapshotUriResponse.Result.Uri;
                    
                    StreamSetup streamSetup = new StreamSetup
                    {
                        Stream = StreamType.RTPUnicast,
                        Transport = new Transport
                        {
                            Protocol = TransportProtocol.RTSP
                        }
                    };
    
    
                    // get stream URI
                    var mediaUri = new MediaUri();
                    mediaUri = await mediaClient.GetStreamUriAsync(streamSetup, ProfileToken);
    
                    string str = mediaUri.Uri;
                    int n = 7;
    
                    str = str.Remove(0, n);
    
    
                    string urlWithCredentials = string.Format("rtsp://{0}:{1}@{2}", userName, password, str);
    
              label3.Text = urlWithCredentials;
    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
    
                ErrorMe(ex.ToString());
    
            }
       }
```

[Wireshark packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk4OP.png)